# How to make pseudo line in tailwind?

Tags: tailwind-css, tailwind-3

I have a block:

```
<div class="height: 400px; padding-left: 20px"></div>
```

How to make vertical line on the left side of block using tailwind?

I try to achive this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question well, but need to read [tailwind docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/) to understand how tailwind works, so here is what I did I hope it's what you are looking for :

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class='h-screen w-screen'>

<div class="h-[400px]  bg-green-300 w-[20px]"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Yes, it is too right solution

Comment: Can you comment each classes? Please

Comment: Or share a link

Comment: @Mamkad here is the [Link](https://play.tailwindcss.com/0dcssMEur9)

Comment: @Dhaifallah Thank you for the hint with the padding . +1up from me ;-)

Comment: @MaikLowrey Thanks mate, your answer is cleaner though +1.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with to divs. You have to use flex box (`flex`) system to align the to divs next to each other. Then you can set the height `h-[400]` and the padding `pl-[20]`.  pl-* means `padding-left`.

**example**

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="flex h-[400px] p-2">
  <div class="bg-blue-700 w-1"></div>
  <div class="pl-[20px]">Hello</div>
</div>
```

**height:auto;**

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="flex h-auto p-2">
  <div class="bg-blue-700 w-1"></div>
  <div class="pl-[20px]">Hello</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, it is! Could you explain for example I have figma design where text has 13px size. How to set this size in tailwind? How to calculate it?

Comment: Can you commend steps: `flex h-96 p-2` and `bg-blue-700 w-1` and `pl-5`

Comment: @Mamkad Thanks. I update my answer.

Comment: What if height is auto?

Comment: h-auto is the tailwind class for height: auto. https://tailwindcss.com/docs/height

Comment: Okay and `p-2` means?

Comment: @Mamkad :-) `p-2` = `padding: 8px 8p 8px 8px`

Comment: @Mamkad In tailwind you will often see `*l-*`, `*r-*`, `*t-*`, `*b-*`. It stands for left, right, top, bottom.

Comment: @MaikLowrey no it actually means `.p-2 {padding: 0.5rem/* 8px */;}`

Comment: Yes you are right!. correct answer would be padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px; @Dhaifallah I updated my comment

Comment: So any value as `p-2` I must multiply 2 * 4? and get in pixels?

Comment: @Mamkad I think * 4 . But you can write in `[nPX]` your custom value

Comment: So, all default props in tailwind in `rems` it means I must set font-size in pixels in html, body as initial?

Comment: @Mamkad That is a good question! https://tailwindcss.com/docs/font-size#using-custom-values